# How to calculate the mean of the top 10% in R

Tags: r, data.table, mean, quantile, percentile

My dataset contains multiple observations for different species. Each species has a different number of observations. Looking for a fast way in R to calculate the mean of the top 10% of values for a given variable for each species.

I figured out how to get a given number of values (i.e., the top 20 values).

```
clim6 <-setDT(range)[order(species, clim6),.SD[1:20],by=species]
write.csv(Bioclimlo6, file = "clim6.csv")
```

I also know that there is a way to trim the dataset to generate a mean of the remaining dataset but I'm not sure how to trim only the bottom 90%.

```
mean(x, trim = 0, na.rm = FALSE)
```

Comment: `mean(x[x >= quantile(x, 0.9, na.rm=TRUE)], na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: Why would you prefer this mean over calculating the 95th percentile of the data?

Answer (score 13):

Mean of top 10% of values, using base R:

```
x = c(1:100,NA)
mean(x[x>=quantile(x, 0.9, na.rm=TRUE)], na.rm=TRUE)
```

Mean of top 10% of values, by grouping variable:

```
# Fake data
dat = data.frame(x=1:100, group=rep(LETTERS[1:3], c(30,30,40)))
```

**With `dplyr`**

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(meanTop10pct = mean(x[x>=quantile(x, 0.9)]))
```

> ```
>    group meanTop10pct
>   (fctr)        (dbl)
> 1      A         29.0
> 2      B         59.0
> 3      C         98.5
> ```

**With `data.table`**

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dat)[, list(meanTop10pct = mean(x[x>=quantile(x, 0.9)])), by=group]
```

> ```
>    group meanTop10pct
> 1:     A         29.0
> 2:     B         59.0
> 3:     C         98.5
> ```

Comment: Is there additionally a way to get the bottom (lowest) 10% of values for a particular variable again grouping by species?

Comment: Yes, just do `x <= quantile(x, 0.1)`. You can choose `x` within any percentile ranges using the `quantile` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
top10_mean <- mean(quantile(x, 0.2, na.rm = TRUE))
```